# Optimizing large scale e-commerce sites

Tags: ecommerce, images, optimization, automation, scalability

I have a few questions regarding optimizing large scale e-commerce sites with getting indexed. Over 1 million pages.

Should you optimize images for e-stores with over 1 million product images?

Should anything be automated for e-stores with over 1 million pages? What can be automated?

Comment: If you have a million products then you have much more to worry about than image optimization. For example, where are your descriptions coming from? Are you scraping or pulling from an API like Amazon? If you are pulling down items from a 3rd party, and cloning/keeping the same *everything*, then you are not going to ranked well or be indexed anywhere near a competitive spot. Optimizing images and pushing feeds isn't going to change that....gotta fix the product datas.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes and as much as possible.**

- Even optimizing a single image has an impact. It saves bandwidth for your visitors and your servers. **Optimizing a million images is a million times more advantageous**.
- Nobody wants to go anything a million times, so **automate everything you can**. Every effort saved gets multiplied the larger your data is.

From this, you can guess that automating the optimization of your images is a necessity!

Answer (score 0):

**Image Optimization**

Every website on the planet should be using image optimization using lossless compression - since whats the point of slowing down the experience for your visitors.

There are a few websites online that can compress images for you in lossless format:

1. [SmushIt](http://www.smushit.com/ysmush.it/)
2. [Jpeg Optimizer](http://jpeg-optimizer.com/)
3. [TinyPNG](http://tinypng.org/)

Since you have a million pages then your most likely require a linux solution or windows commandline tool, take a look at

1. [PNGOut](http://advsys.net/ken/utils.htm)
2. [OptiPNG](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/)
3. [PngCrush](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/)
4. [JpegTran](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_jpegtran.htm)

**Automation**

There is just too many automation things you can do to a e-store so I'm only going to list a few otherwise I think my keyboard will break before getting to the end.

1. **Automated SEO** You can use various automated SEO plugins that can make the URLS, Page Titles, Meta Descriptions for you.
2. **Automated [Rich Snippets](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99170)** and markups using [Schema](http://schema.org/)
3. **Automated [Site Map](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156184)** Creation
4. **Automated Emailing** [on Orders and Newsletters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marketing_automation)
5. **Automated uploading** of products to [Google Shop using CVS](http://www.google.co.uk/merchants)
6. **Automated Cloud Optimisation** automaticlly duplicates content on the cloud using API
7. **Automated image Optimisation** Using Various Tools (Some Listed Above)
8. **Any Automation** is good as long as it doesn't result in ruining your audiences experience.